# Cronjob linux server logging

Tags: php, linux, apache, logging, cron

I have some cronjobs running on my linux server. These cronjobs are just executing some PHP scripts. What I want to do is to log any possible outputs these scripts would have given.

I want to use the output as given by the command:

```
wget -O /logs/logfile /pathofthefolder/script.php
```

The problem is that this command overwrites the previous logfile, thus the logfile only contains the output of the last execution, which is kinda useless for logging.

I tried adding an -a for appending instead of overwriting, but that didn't work.

I also tried with only an -a like this:

```
wget -a /logs/logfile http://example.com/script.php
```

But also that didn't work, I get the information of the download in the logfile as such:

```
-2014-05-27 21:41:01--  http://example.com/script.php
Resolving example.com (example.com)... [ip address of my site]
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|[ip address of my site]|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `script.php.4'
     0K
```

So the information of the HTTP request is being stored in the logfile, and the output of every request is saved in a seperate file with increasing numbers, script.php.1, script.php.2 and so on. Which isn't quite what I want, I'd prefer to have it all in one file, I don't need the HTTP info.

Update:
So I know that it would be easier via the php or lynx command, but those commands are not installed on the server. I'm kinda stuck with the wget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
wget -qO- "http://example.com/script.php?parameter=value&extraparam=othervalue" >> /logs/logfile
```

Comment: This has the same problem. The HTTP REQUEST data gets logged, and the actual output of the script ends up in a seperate file for every execution.

Comment: Okay I tried this. This gives the same result as the two I mentioned in my post combined. The HTTP Request data ends up in the logfile while the output of the last execution ends up in script.php in the root directory.

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly! Have to work on the formatting a little bit, but it does what I want. Thank you very much! The idea is, the script doesn't output anything, but in case it throws a PHP error, the output will be logged, making it easier for me to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that this no longer works when you try to add parameters to the php file? Like script.php?parameter=value&extraparam=othervalue

Comment: You should quote the url

Comment: Ah Yes thanks, now it works. It is so annoying to have this shared hosting where I have no feedback on what I am trying, so have to use trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try rewriting your cronjobs to use the php interpreter instead of wget:

```
php -f /path/to/file
```

This will execute a local (!) php file and write the output to command line.

You can easily redirect this output to apppend to a file:

```
php -f /path/to/file >> /logs/logfile
```

(to overwrite instead of append, use a single `>`)

If you need the error messages as well, you need to redirect both stdout and stderr:

```
php -f /path/to/file >> /logs/logfile 2>&1
```

In case you don't have/cannot install the php executable, you can use (if installed) curl to get a similar result as with wget (see other answers):

```
curl http://localhost/your/file.php >> /logs/logfile
```

Comment: Yeah I preferred it this way too. But the problem is that the PHP command is not installed on the server. Thus I get the following log. "-: php: command not found".

And since it is not my own server, it's a shared host, I can't install any new functions.

Comment: In this case, yes, use user1279647 's solution, if that works for you. If you have curl installed, you can try my updated answer, but it will not give you stderr, as with wget. (Formatting may be better, though).

Comment: Jup this has the same result. Thanks.